# How do I find when my license expires?

Tags: license

I have a general license but I do not know when it expires, please help.

Comment: What country or legal jurisdiction?

Comment: Hello Diane, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: There is only one person with your name on qrz.com in the FCC database, and she is a Technician whose license expires in 2027. I take it from that that you might be outside the USA? If so, which country or jurisdiction?

Comment: Diane, if one of the answers here worked for you, kindly upvote it and [mark it as the accepted answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (big checkmark next to the answer). Otherwise, the system will keep pushing your question to the top.

Answer (score 2):

For the United States, the FCC has an online license search function, currently at: https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/searchLicense.jsp

You can choose to type in your call sign to look it up, or if you don't know your call sign, you can look up by name.

Comment: Good! The name she gave *might* not be her real name (and there are good reasons for doing that, such as for her own safety). Thus my comment to her about marking one of these answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The expiration date may be on the paper copy of your license.

If you lost your paper copy, you simply can do a Google search (or other search engine search) for your callsign + "FCC".  For a U.S. license, that will usually find the wireless2.FCC.gov web site with information on when the license with that callsign was issued plus its expiration date (assuming its still valid).

If you are not licensed in the U.S., replace "FCC" with the governmental licensing entity (or an appropriate abbreviation) in your jurisdiction, which will work if its records are public.